# Compact and closed problem

Tags: real-analysis

> If $A \subset R^k$ and $B \subset R^k$, define A+B to be the set of all sums $x+y$ with $x \in A$, $y \in B$. If K is compact and C is closed in $R^k$, prove that K+C is closed.

Closed definition: A set E is closed if every limit point of E is a point of E.

Definition of compact sets: a set S of real numbers is called compact if every sequence in s has a subsequence that converges to an element again contained in S.

Does episilon Delta language work in here? How am I supposed to go about proving this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to use sequential criterion.

Suppose $x_n +y_n$ be a sequence in $K+C$ which converges to some $z$ in $ \Bbb R ^k $.

Since,  $K$ is compact, $x_n$ has a convergent subsequence, say $x_{r_n}$ which converges to some $x$ in $K$

So, $x_{r_n}+y_{r_n}$ is convergent hence $y_{r_n}$ converges to $z-x$. Hence by closure property of $C$, $z-x\in C$.

So, $z=x+(z-x) \in K+C$

Hence $K+C$ is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $k_n+c_n$ converges towards $c$, $k_n\in K, c_n\in C$, there exists subsequequence $k_{p_n}$ which converges towards $k\in K$, since $K$ is compact

$k_{p_n}+c_{p_n}-k_{p_n}=c_{p_n}$ converges towards $x-k=c\in C$ since it is the sum of two converging sequences and  $C$ is closed, this implies that $k_{p_n}+c_{p_n}$ converges towards $k+c$ and $k_n+c_n$ converges towards $k+c$.